# Do you still get stabbed if you decide to draw your gun?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

In the scene where you are asking for the tickets to the guy talking on the phone. If you demand the tickets he stabs you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you decide to draw your gun, the "ticket teller" will instead turn around, shove you away, and "close" the metal curtain, for that booth. He will come out later, and you can kill him then.

No, you will not be stabbed.

Comment: So no bandage around the hand for the rest of the game?

Comment: No bandage, so the outcome of this situation is merely a cosmetic change

Comment: It's worth mentioning that choosing no action in the allotted time will still get you knifed doing the same thing as if you still demanded the tickets.

Answer (score 4):

Draw your gun and the teller raises his hands but the guys behind you start shooting, the teller will attack you after the shootout and you can still access the office.

Proof

Comment: Elizabeth also has alternate dialogue for this action.

Answer (score -4):

If you get stabbed the wound decreases your reload speed but the bandage covers the "AD" brand on your hand making it take more time for others to identify you. Relationship with Elizabeth will grow in which she'll be more willing to throw your health but if you "shoot first" it may take time for you to connect with her. The rest of the game is spent with the bandage.

Comment: Is there anything to support this? Just curious.

Comment: Considering the hyper-tutorialized nature of the game and the lack of any in-game indication that this is happening, this answer seems extremely suspicious. As Retrosaur said, do you have any references or proof that this is true?